# How to run Java programs from the terminal?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, terminal, osx-lion

I am trying to run a Java program from my Terminal. I have Mac OS X 10.7.

> teamL javac -jar kxml2-2.3.0.jar XMLHandler.java ServiceEndpoint.java TeamL.java

This is my Eclipse class file structure:

[image: eclipse class file structure]

I am not able to find why is this throwing `Unable to access jarfile kxml2-2.3.0.jar`?

Comment: for me it looks like it doesn't find the jarfile

Comment: @Vinisa, Accept the answer and close this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are referencing any external libraries, then you have to add them to the `classpath`. You can add it during compilation of the classes this way.

Go to the src directory and :

```
javac -classpath ".:<path_to_jar_file>" teamL/*.java
```

TO execute :

```
java -cp ".:<path_to_jar_file>" teamL.<class_name>
```

if your are using eclipse, then go to `<project_directory>/bin/` here you can find the compiled classes (so you dont have to compile them) and directly run them using the above `java` command

Note: Since your classes are packaged under `teamL` package, you have to run the classes from outside the package by specifying the fully qualified name like `teamL.ServiceEndpoint`

Comment: You cant use `-jar` for compilation, `-jar` is used to execute a jar application directly. I don't know where exactly your project folder is ! I guess you must be knowing how to change the current directory using the `cd` command in the terminal. Just `cd` to `Documents/adsproject/ADS_Deliverable1/src/` in the terminal, then `javac -classpath ".:<path_to_jar_file>" teamL/*.java`

Comment: ok looking at the screenshot, i see your project directory is `home/Users/vsingh3/Documents/adsproject/ADS_Deliverable1` open a new terminal, then type `cd Documents/adsproject/ADS_Deliverable1/src` Then `javac -classpath ".:Documents/adsproject/ADS_Deliverable1/<path_to_jar_file>" teamL/*.java`

Comment: Thanks but I just noticed your comment about if you are running on eclipse. So, I guess I need not compile. Another thing is that since my jar file was not found so I copy pasted it in each of the folders. I have all my source files and jar file in `ADS_Deliverable1->src->teamL`. I am now running it like > `teamL  java -cp -jar kxml2-2.3.0.jar XMLHandler.java ServiceEndpoint.java TeamL.java` Why is this throwing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kxml2-2/3/0/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kxml2-2.3.0.jar`

Comment: The same is working in windows eclipse correctly. Also why can't I run the same from my eclipse?

Comment: As i told earlier, don't use `-jar` to add jar files into the `classpath` ! to make it easier, copy the jar file inside the src folder, then `javac -cp . teamL.<main_class>` so if `ServiceEndpoint` is your main class, then you have to use `java -cp . teamL.ServiceEndpoint` 

lemme know if you could run this successfully..

Comment: Why is there a `.` after cp and I have my jar file in src and in teamL so I tried `java -cp . teamL.kxml2-2.3.0.jar teamL.XMLHandler teamL.ServiceEndpoint teamL.TeamL` and `java -cp . kxml2-2.3.0.jar teamL.XMLHandler teamL.ServiceEndpoint teamL.TeamL`. I am inside `teamL` directory. Getting `ClassNotFoundException` for jar file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3897/discussion-between-rakesh-and-vinisa)

Comment: Figured it out using eclipse itself with the help of @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Have you added that jar to the classpath when you execute the program on the command line? e.g.

java -classpath location_of_jar ...

Answer (score 0):

`javac` is a command to compile instead of that you should use the command Java.

- First set the classpath
- Then run it like this

> java -classpath %classpathVariable% %YourClass% %arguments...

[Running a Java Program from Command Prompt](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) this could give you a better idea is for Windows but is similar.