# How to make Eclipse run my program in a terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

Sometimes, the console in Eclipse just isn't enough, or my program has to be run in a terminal of some sort. How would I achieve this?

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 on a MacBook.

**Edit:**
I know how to run Java programs from a terminal, but what I want is Eclipse to do this automatically when I press the run button.

Comment: [How to run Java programs from the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598171/how-to-run-java-programs-from-the-terminal) ?

Comment: @Perdomoff That is an entirely different question, that one is about why eclipse doesn't find the jarfile or something, this one is about how to make eclipse run the program in the terminal by default. Sorry if it's unclear.

Comment: just click run... it runs stuff in its own terminal.

Comment: It is possible and already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571222/eclipse-plugin-that-opens-a-command-line-in-eclipse) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689991/how-do-i-get-to-the-command-line-in-eclipse)

There is one more [link]http://idiotechie.com/how-to-use-cmd-prompt-inside-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

> **Making Eclipse do it for you isn't possible**

To do it manually:

First, go to the directory with your `*.java` file.  To go to the directory, use the `cd` command.  Then, run `javac yourfile.java`.  Lastly, `java yourfile`

Comment: But I don't want to do it manually, I want to make Eclipse do it for me.

Comment: Eclipse to do it for you?  That isn't possible

Comment: To make Eclipse open up a terminal and automatically do this when I press the run button. I've edited the question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: @Enerccio how so?