# java run include classpath from terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal, jsoup

Practising using jsoup. I use linux and program from the terminal command line. Inside a folder I have the jsoup-1.8.3.jar, and a java file containing basic code to get a title and show it back. for reference sake here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
class WebCrawler{

     public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
            String title = doc.title();  
            System.out.println("title is: " + title);  
     }  

}
```

I think I've been able to compile the class file using the command:

```
javac -cp "jsoup-1.8.3.jar" WebCrawler.java
```

which gives back no error.

However when trying what I think should be:

```
java -cp "jsoup-1.8.3.jar" WebCrawler
```

It will then say "Error: Could not find or load main class WebCrawler
". Upon trying to tab in the information, I find after the input of the jar file when I press W and tab, it will not find the WebCrawer class file ,which is there in the same folder along side the jar file and source.

This should be a basic fix, what am I typing wrong?

Comment: `java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar:. WebCrawler`. The current directory needs to be in the classpath, since your class is in the default package, and the class file is in the current directory. You shouldn't have source files, class files, and libraries in the same directory though. Organize your project a little bit: source files under src, class files under classes, libraries under lib.

Comment: Finally figured it out. For future reference I did "javac -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar: WebCrawler.java" then "java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar: WebCrawler".

@JB Nizet - thanks, I just figured it out at the same time you posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Java programs from the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598171/how-to-run-java-programs-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Answer proposed by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

> ```
> java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar:. WebCrawler
> ```
>
> The current directory needs to be in the classpath, since your class is in the default package, and the class file is in the current directory. You shouldn't have source files, class files, and libraries in the same directory though. Organize your project a little bit: source files under src, class files under classes, libraries under lib.